# Is IIS configuration necessary to serve ArcGIS Server wms services?

Tags: arcgis-server, iis

with ArcGIS for Server server 10.3 on windows Server 2012 and I would like to serve wms services over the internet. I have a reverse proxy set up which directs requests to an end point in ArcGIS server, but am getting a 403 forbidden answer from the server. How can I find out if this an IIS issue or an ArcGIS Server issue? It is necessary to configure IIS in any way before administering wms over the internet?

Comment: Could be also a problem of http and https. Is your url from outside maybe https and is changed to http or vice versa?

Comment: My reverse proxy is in a DMZ and is protected with https. I think the reverse proxy is working ok otherwise I wouldn´t get the 403: no permission error. I am just not sure whether this is a typical webadapter configuration matter or firewall/nat problem. My question is really, how can I test where the problem is stemming from?IIS, WebAdapter or Firewall?

Comment: You could try step by step. On your server you could check if you can access the wms there (for example via the browser and the getcapabilities request). When its working there,  its a connection problem from outside.